# remove dashes from each value in an array, then rebuild array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im having a lot of trouble with this, and I'm now sure why.

I have a dynamic array, that can consist of 1 or more values:

```
[array] => Array
    (
        [0] => blurb
        [1] => news
        [2] => entertainment
        [3] => sci
        [4] => diablo-3
    )
```

Here is my model

```
    public function create_session_filter($filters)
    {
        $array = split("\|", $filters);
        $filter['filter'] = $array;
        $this->session->unset_userdata('filter');
        $this->session->set_userdata($filter);
    }
```

When the array $filters is run, i need to remove any dashes from any of the individual array values and replace them with spaces.

This is producing some funky results:

```
    public function create_session_filter($filters)
    {
        $filterarray = array();
        $array = split("\|", $filters);
        foreach ($array as $filter) 
        {
            print_r($filter);
            $filterspace = implode(' ', explode('-', $filter));
            $filterarray = array_push($filterarray, $filterspace);
        }
        $filter['filter'] = $filterarray;
        $this->session->unset_userdata('filter');
        $this->session->set_userdata($filter);
    }
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the exploding and imploding isn't really necessary. Nor would you need to create a new array. You can cycle through your values by reference, and modify them in a one-liner:

```
$array = array( "blurb", "news", "diblo-3" );

$array = str_replace( "-", " ", $array );
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
  [0] => blurb
  [1] => news
  [2] => diblo 3
)
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/up0VoZ21

Comment: You can just call `str_replace()` on the array.

Comment: @salathe Excellent advice. I wasn't aware that you could provide an array as the subject, and that the function would then act on each of the values within. Very cool.